# ruby collect unique elements

Tags: ruby, hash

I have some array of hashes

```
a = [{name:"x", long:1.0, lat:2.0}, 
     {name:"y", long:2.0, lat:3.0}, 
     {name:"z", long:1.0, lat:2.0}]
```

how to delete `{name:"x", long:1.0, lat:2.0}`, which coords are equal of last element, Other words I need to leave last (in my case: with `name:"z"`) hash with unique coords and drop all previous element with same coords

Comment: I have never encountered such a problem... I need some algorithmic idea, ruby code i can write myself

Comment: Yeah, do write some code, please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `Array#uniq` with a block:

```
a.uniq { |item| [item[:lat], item[:long]] }
```

The return value of the block is used as the value to compare for uniqueness.

It's not clear why you want "x" to be deleted and not "z", but you could achieve that with the example data set by reversing the array before calling `uniq` on it.

Comment: a.reverse.uniq { |item| [item[:lat], item[:long]] }.reverse helped me!